# Inject my dependency into CustomQueryCompiler

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement my variant of cache for entity framework core.
What I did is inherit

public class CustomQueryCompiler : QueryCompiler

and then I trying to inject distributed cache into constructor of my CustomQueryCompiler, but it can't resolve it.Getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication6.CustomQueryCompiler'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
```

I don't understand why, and how to fix it.

My startup look like this:

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {    
            services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
                options.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379,password=P@55w0rd,allowAdmin=true,ssl=False,abortConnect=false");

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
                    options.ReplaceService<IQueryCompiler, CustomQueryCompiler>();
                }
            ); 
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

And constructor of CustomQueryCompiler

```cs
  public class CustomQueryCompiler : QueryCompiler
    {
        private readonly IQueryModelGenerator _queryModelGenerator;
        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

        public CustomQueryCompiler(IQueryContextFactory queryContextFactory,
            ICompiledQueryCache compiledQueryCache,
            ICompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator compiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator,
            IDatabase database,
            IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Query> logger,
            ICurrentDbContext currentContext,
            IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDistributedCache distributedCache) : 
            base(queryContextFactory, compiledQueryCache, compiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator, database, logger, currentContext, queryModelGenerator)
        {
            _queryModelGenerator = queryModelGenerator;
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out. 
EF Core maintain its own IoC Container.
So you need to pass existing services into its container.

I had to do next thing.  Hope it helps someone else.

```cs
  services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
  services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IQueryCompiler), typeof(CustomQueryCompiler), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

  services.AddDbContext < AppDbContext > (options => {
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));

   options.UseInternalServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
  });
```